# Joinging Query Django

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class PopSummary(models.Model):

available_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name="email address",
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
    default=''
)     

requested_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)  
approved_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)  
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
approve = models.BooleanField(default=False)

popuser = models.ForeignKey(RequestPop, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='popuser',null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return "{}-{}".format(self.email,self.available_pop)
```

Another Table:

```
class RequestPop(models.Model):

request_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=False,null=True)

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
available_pop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):

    return "{}-{}".format(self.user,self.request_pop)
```

I want to make the query in inner join or other way so that:

```
select all from RequestPop where PopSummary.approve=True
```

I run the follwing query.

```
queryset = RequestPop.objects.filter(popuser__approve=True).all()
```

but it seems to be incorrect. So what should be the solution for it please.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect as the RequestPop doesn't have a popuser attribute, you can go the other way round.

```
queryset = PopSummary.objects.filter(approve=True)
for obj in queryset
    reqpop=obj.popuser_set.all()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'PopSummary' object has no attribute 'popuser_set'

Comment: you can `print(dir(obj))` and you will find it.

Comment: `PointRequestedByAllUser
    reqpop=obj.popuser_set.all()
AttributeError: 'PopSummary' object has no attribute 'popuser_set'`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will suggest using Foreign keys instead of positive so that you can run queries in more pythonic ways

You can write this line as

```
requested_pop = model.ForeignKey(RequestPop,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name="pop_summaries")
```

Now you can write the query as below

```
request_pops = RequestPop.objects.filter(pop_summaries__approve=True)
```

This is exactly what you want to achieve.

So always try to use foreign keys instead of integer as reference so that Django can create join queries for them while writing in more pythonic way.

Comment: Already have this: `popuser = models.ForeignKey(RequestPop, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='popuser',null=True)`

Comment: then use popuser instead of pop_summaries in my answer it will work no need for foreign keys editing.